# Restricting clients from subscribing to channels in Faye nodejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, faye

I have a rails app that has a messaging feature. To make it a live service I have setup Faye (NodeJS version) to only allow incoming messages from my rails application. It does this by Rails passing it a specific token and if the token matches the master token it then pushes that incoming message.

What I would like to do now is restrict who can subscribe to specific channels. Mainly so that tech savy users dont inspect the channel name and then fiddle with it to subscribe to channels they shouldn't have access too.

Here is a gist of server https://gist.github.com/aliuk2012/e5c82aec6b7f0fba53d9 you will see around line 40 I have attempted to simply rejected the subscription. I get the console log but if I push a message to any channel the user still gets the message.

I just need some guidance on how to restrict/unsubscribe users if they attempt to subscribe to a channel. Later on I'm planning on passing the CSRF token from rails app or something unique for a particular user from the client to faye which will then call a rails endpoint to validate the user before they can subscribe to that channel.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using Pusher.com for this, rather than maintaining your own Faye server? It makes private channels, and auth so SO easy. https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_private_channels

Comment: Yes thanks but would prefer to keep it in-house.

Comment: Definitely cheaper! :-)

Comment: From the docs.  engine.subscribe(clientId, channel, function(successful)

`    bayeux.on('subscribe', function(clientId,channel,cb){
      console.log('Lets reject this client ' + clientId);
       cb(false);
      return false;
    });`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs.

engine.subscribe(clientId, channel, function(successful)

```
   bayeux.on('subscribe', function(clientId,channel,cb){  
      console.log('Lets reject this client ' + clientId);  
       cb(false);  
      return false;  
    });`
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs you referring too?
I tried that on my line 40 but it complained that cb (which i'm assuming to be callback) is undefined.

Comment: Looks like that is more related to setting up your own engine, but perhaps that leads you down the proper path...